# Integrating without tricks

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral is $\int\frac{\sqrt x -1}{\sqrt x}$. I have asked the opposite question on this site where the denominator would be the numerator and the numerator would be the denominator. I understand how that would work using ln. Is this similar to that.

I am trying to do this without using any techniques (eg. no u-sub, no parts...) just using what I know about basic integrals, by inspection. I tried to pull the denominator into the numerator to get some constant that I can pull in front of the integrand, but I have been unsuccessful. I am looking to see how I should simplify this and break it apart into smaller integrals that are easy to compute. Thank You.

Comment: Write the integrand as a difference of two powers of $x$ and then use the basic "integrate a power of $x$" rule along with additivity of integration.

Comment: Now you have 4 identical answers to look at!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write $$\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 1-x^{-1/2}$$
and then
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}}\; dx = \int (1-x^{-1/2})\; dx = \boxed{x-2x^{1/2} + C}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx
$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{\sqrt x -1 }{\sqrt x}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand:

$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int 1 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int 1 -x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx
$$

can you do from this?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is

$$f (x)=2 (\sqrt {x}-1)\frac {1}{2\sqrt {x}} $$

thus

$$\int f (x)dx=(\sqrt {x}-1)^2+C $$

Comment: OP specified "no u-sub"